User is authenticated, but AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser() still hides the page
I'm working on a web application (ASP .NET Core) which will run within our organization, and the production version will use Active Directory for access control. I and my coworker should be able to develop on computers which aren't in the AD domain.
This week, my coworker, while developing on a machine within the domain, added LDAP-based authentication. She also turned off access for unauthenticated users. I added a hardcoded user class as suggested here and an environment variable in launchSettings.json which controls whether to use her Active Directory authentication (when the app is run in-network) or my mock user (in a launch profile intended for out-of-network). For now, we haven't added any authorization filters to individual controllers, views or actions.
Now Program.cs contains following rows:
if(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("authenticationType")=="mock")
{
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication").AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions,
                              MockAuthenticatedUser>("BasicAuthentication", null);
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
}
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});

And when I launch the project locally, nothing is displayed. The browser just displays a page consisting of an empty body tag. To get my app to display, I have to comment out the builder.Services.AddAuthorization line. In both cases, I'm using the correct launch profile with authenticationType set to mock.
At first I thought that I have made a mistake in writing my mock user or in setting up its authentication. So in Index.cshtml, I added a display of the user's name and authentication status:
@{
    var user =  ContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
    var claims = user.Identities.First().Claims.ToList();
    var userLabelBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    var userName = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Split('/').Last().Equals("name")).Value.ToString();
    userLabelBuilder.Append(userName);
    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    { userLabelBuilder.Append(", authenticated"); }
    else { userLabelBuilder.Append(", not authenticated"); }
}
<span style="margin-right: 2em;">logged in as @userLabelBuilder.ToString()</span>

And when I start the app (with the authorization fallback policy commented out, so the app will display), this produces the line logged in as admin, authenticated.
So, my question is: Why is it that user.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true, but AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser() results in the app not being displayed? And what can I do so my mock user becomes usable wherever the app requires authentication?

Are you having a Role issue?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@jdweng there aren't role checks anywhere in the app yet. The only place with a policy is the row options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();  and when I comment it out, the app runs properly.

Your issue might stem from a mismatch in the authentication scheme. make sure your mock authentication scheme is set as the default in AddAuthentication. Check if your MockAuthenticatedUser properly sets the AuthenticationType on ClaimsIdentity. try to use some logging in your mock handler to verify that it's executing and creating the expected identity. Also, test the application of authorization policies by manually invoking the IAuthorizationService and logging the results.

Read following : https://www.seeleycoder.com/blog/policy-based-authorization-aspnetcore/
